# Node Express API + Front-End

Tags: node.js, rest, api, express

I'm coding my first "solo" nodejs webapp. Its based on a previous app (that I coded by following some kind of tutorial/course) which was an Express REST API that allows you to add/remove/update/list a Todo list. I've also implemented user authentication using jwt/bcrypt. All this is stored in a MongoDB database.

Also note that all the endpoints return JSON.

I'm now trying to add a front-end to the app. The API endpoints are at `/api/endpoint1`, `/api/endpoint2`, etc., and the views are rendered on `/view1`, `/view2`, etc. I'm doing this on purpose so that I can get the responses in plain JSON from the API, or show it in a webpage rendered.

I started by using jQuery's ajax to make the calls but I realized this was not the way I wanted to do this. I removed all the js scripts on my webpage and started working directly on the server, rendering the pages with the info fetched from the api.

This is what I have now:

**server.js (main file) [sample]**

```
// RENDER 'GET TODOs'
app.get('/todos', authenticate, (req, res) => {
    let auth = req.cookies['x-auth'];
    request({
        url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/todos',
        headers: {
            'x-auth': auth
        }
    }, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
            return res.status(response.statusCode || 500).send('Error'); // TODO
        }
        let bodyJSON = JSON.parse(body);
        res.render('todos', {
            title: 'Todo App - Todos',
            todos: bodyJSON.todos
        });
    });
});

// API endpoint to 'GET TODOs' (JSON)
app.get('/api/todos', authenticate, (req, res) => {
    Todo.find({
        _creator: req.user._id
    }).then((todos) => {
        res.send({todos});
    }, (err) => {
        res.status(400).send(err);
    });
});
```

I don't know why, but all this looks weird to me. I'm wondering if this is how I'm supposed to do this. I mean, is this a good approach/practice on making a API+front-end node app ?

Also, I'm using an auth middleware twice: in the views and in the API itself. I guess this is OK?

It would probably be better to use React/Angular but this is such a small app and I just wanted to make a really simple front-end.

Comment: You can avoid using auth middleware twice if you want.  If you want to authenticate all api calls, you could just do `app.use('/api', authenticate);`

Comment: Not all endpoints need authentication. For example, /api/login. When I said I was using the same auth middleware twice is because I'm checking for auth both on the front-end client views and on the api itself. So if you use the website path /todos you need to be logged in (aka x-auth cookie). And if you try to get json data from the api by accessing /api/todos you'd also need to be logged in (aka x-auth header)

Answer (score 0):

Just keep things simple.

If you go with server-side HTML rendering, you don't need a REST API, just drop it. You need an API in case of an ajax frontend or mobile app.

If you needed a combined approach (server-side rendering + mobile app or server side rendering with some ajax), at the very first step you would want to isolate your database querying code into a separate module (which is actually always a good idea) and use the module from your API and from your views directly, avoiding API usage from server-side views.

This way you will eliminate excessive auth and make debugging much easier, also your code will become cleaner, thus more maintainable.

Also, React is not that complex, i would definitely give it a shot :)

Comment: I'll take a look at React but I wanted to learn nodejs before.

Comment: In case I open the API to external access, I need it to return JSON. In this case, I need the front-end to fetch data from that API. What I understand from your comment is that in this case, Id separate the API from the front-end app. Am I correct ?

Comment: I know that I could render directly from the api routes and that would make things easy but this is a way to practise my nodejs/express skills. I still need to use routes, refactor the project structure (using controllers for example), and a couple more things. I wanted to do this before I move on to React. I could use a boilerplate and just edit it but I feel I learn better this way.

Comment: @nip Well, if you know that you're doing a wierd thing, and you do this intentionally, while you see a more proper way, what is the real question?

Comment: Im not following. I'll try to explain better: I want to: 1. Make an API that responds with json (so any user can do whatever they want with the info (eg: use it in an app, on their website, whatever..). 2. Make a front-end for that api. For this scenario, what would be the right approach ? 1. Make the API on a nodejs app (and nothing more); 2. Make the front-end on another nodejs app; ?

Comment: found a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23871853/concerns-about-separating-front-end-and-back-end-with-a-nodejs-ui-server and the answer seems to point in the same direction as Im heading.